# UNUserNotificationCenter/ UserNotification not found in Xcode 11 iOS13 -

Tags: swift, xcode11, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to setup Notifcations on Xcode 11 in iOS13 but i tried adding the linked frameworks(in pic) but still doesn't recognize the module. Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UNUserNotificationCenter


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        // Request permission to display alerts and play sounds.
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
           { (granted, error) in
              // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
           }
        return true
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Do not post code as pictures. Please replace the picture with text (same for your answer).

Comment: updated @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
import UNUserNotificationCenter
```

to

```
import UserNotifications
```

Comment: Also you should not need to do any manual linking with frameworks as you are doing; delete all those. `import` with a module name links you automatically.

Comment: i tried UserNotifications and it didnt recognize it either , the only one it offered tho from autocomplete was UNUserNoticaitionCenter but still says it doesnt recognize it

Comment: I assure you that `import UserNotifications` works.

Comment: ok but how can i get it to show up or recognize it as a module, because it keeps saying module not found ?

Answer (score 0):

For me to fix this i had to remove the `import UNUserNotifications`  and just write the code below . Not sure why but `import UserNotfications` was not working for me . Remove linked frameworks if added.

Also I found the fix on Apples website here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        // Request permission to display alerts and play sounds.
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
           { (granted, error) in
              // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
           }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: That’s impossible. If you say “UNUserNotificationCenter” in your code, it won’t compile unless you import UserNotifications. Plus how is this code different from what you had before?

Comment: Idk why it worked but it’s the only way I could build and have it run successfully. I removed the import for UNUserNotificationCenter and just called it as shown in code. It is even mentioned on apples website I posted link

Comment: Apple website about UNUserNotificationCenter : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications

Answer (score 0):

Just retried this and now Xcode is working fine with just `UserNotfications` and doesnt now recognize `UNUserNotificationCenter`